# Is sys.exit equivalent to raise SystemExit?

Tags: python, exception, exit

According to the documentation on [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) and [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit), it seems that

```
def sys.exit(return_value=None):  # or return_value=0
    raise SystemExit(return_value)
```

is that correct or does `sys.exit` do something else before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [`Python/sysmodule.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e47e00723e5d/Python/sysmodule.c#l262), raising `SystemExit` is all it does.

```c
static PyObject *
sys_exit(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *exit_code = 0;
    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "exit", 0, 1, &exit_code))
        return NULL;
    /* Raise SystemExit so callers may catch it or clean up. */
    PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_SystemExit, exit_code);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see at source code https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Python/sysmodule.c

```
static PyObject *
sys_exit(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *exit_code = 0;
    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "exit", 0, 1, &exit_code))
        return NULL;
    /* Raise SystemExit so callers may catch it or clean up. */
    PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_SystemExit, exit_code);
    return NULL;
}
```

it's only raise SystemExit and doesn't do anything else

Comment: thanks :) by the way, if you click on a line number on github, you get a link to that, e.g. https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Python/sysmodule.c#L207

Answer (score 3):

Yes, raising `SystemExit` and calling `sys.exit` are functionally equivalent. [See `sys` module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ef4bc37aa5e05910fbdfe7b804a8a5855d87652/Python/sysmodule.c#L262).

The `PyErr_SetObject` function is how CPython implements the raising of a Python exception.

Comment: thanks - note that when linking to specific lines in github code, it is recommended to press `y` first in order to get the canonical URL for the commit you're currently at, e.g. today https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ef4bc37aa5e05910fbdfe7b804a8a5855d87652/Python/sysmodule.c#L262 - future commits may severely shift the line